# is there a solderless solution for component with pins 1.70mm apart?

Tags: pcb, soldering, breadboard, pins, prototyping

I have a CAT4101 http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/CAT4101-D.PDF constant current LED driver which has 5 pins at 1.70 mm BSC apart.

As I am a newbie I would prefer to use only a solderless breadboard, however standard these have pin distances of 2.54mm.

My entire prototype will be deployed on a solderless breadboard so I would like to find a solution to use the CAT4101.

I would like to avoid having to solder 5 wires directly onto the pins as these are so close and I am not really sure how well I can get this job done. Soldering the component on some other type of prototyping board would already be easier and then I could get the wires from the board to connect with the breadboard. But I am not really sure what's available out there

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use some adapter board

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a break-out board. In this case, you need one for a TO-263 5-pin package:

[image]

Nowadays, there's a huge selection of boards available from different manufacturers. Some of them even supply the boards pre-populated:

[image]